# AngularJS Http Post Error: Unexpected request: POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i encounter some issues that i cant able to send the http post request to the server, i m using phonegap to build a application which is using angularjs, may i know how to use angularjs to do a post request? And my code is like this

```js
 .controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http , $state, $ionicPopup, AuthService) {
    $scope.login = function(data) {
      AuthService.login(data.username, data.password).then(function TestController($scope) {
        $scope.username = $http({
          url: 'http://samedomain.com/GetPersons',
          method: "POST",
          data: email="email",
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.data = data; // how do pass this to $scope.persons?
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          alert(error);
          $scope.status = status;
        });

      });
    };
```

After i ran this i got some error like

```js
Error: Unexpected request: POST http://192.168.30.196:8086/user/login
No more request expected
    at $httpBackend (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1418:9)
    at sendReq (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24793:9)
    at serverRequest (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24503:16)
    at processQueue (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29127:28)
    at http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29143:27
    at Scope.$eval (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30395:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30211:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30503:24)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:65426:13)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16787:11)
 ReferenceError: error is not defined
    at http://192.168.30.60:3000/js/controllers.js:82:17
    at http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24540:13
    at processQueue (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29127:28)
    at http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29143:27
    at Scope.$eval (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30395:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30211:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30503:24)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:65426:13)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16787:11)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (http://192.168.30.60:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16775:9)
```

Comment: The way you send data to your post request is wrong you should write 
data:{email:"emailaddress"}  instead of data: email="email"

Comment: In `alert(error)` `error` is not defined. .error is different than error in alert.

Comment: Is this in a unit test? If not, you should **not** be loading `angular-mocks.js`. If it is in a test, you would need to set up an expected POST request in `$httpBackend`

Answer (score 0):

@user3273700 and @varit05 are totally right. Also, the `TestController` that you have as a callback to the `AuthService.login()` should NOT be defined this way. You are definitely mistaken about how controllers should be used. The callback to login method should be a normal function with no parameters.

Change this:

```
AuthService.login(data.username, data.password).then(function TestController($scope) {
```

to this:

```
AuthService.login(data.username, data.password).then(function () {
```

Comment: The name given to the callback function does not matter. You're right about not adding `$scope` as an argument though I would assume OP should pass *something* in, such as the promise resolution value